# AWS CodeCommit : How to get current branch package.xml file to deploy only the changes using yaml file

Tags: yaml, pipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, salesforce-sfdx

I have created a Branche for AWS CodeCommit repository and am able to add the source code using vscode. My problem here is am not able to get the current branch pakage.xml file or the recent component changes using "sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml" command in yaml file it is deploying all the source code from master branch to salesforce org instead of current branch xml file.

Can any one help me with the SFDX command or any other way to achieve this. Thanks.